# Does this code call a class method from a class variable?

Tags: php, class, virtuemart

I am trying to understand this line in the source of Virtuemart:

```
<?php
echo $product->images[0]->displayMediaThumb('class="browseProductImage" style="border-radius: 10px; border: 2px solid #8C9622"', false);
?>
```

It looks like a method is called by a class property  (in this case an object/array `$product->images[0]`) and that that property is passed as a parameter to the method. 
But I cannot find any example of this in the PHP handbook. Can someone please explain or point me to the relevant documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down.  `$product` is obviously an object.  `->images[0]` references a property on that object.  Specifically it's the first element of a property that's an array.  `->displayMediaThumb(...)` is calling a method of an object.  Therefore `images` must be an array of objects.

"That property is passed as a parameter to the method" is incorrect.
`displayMediaThumb` is being called for the first object within `$product`'s `$images`.

Comment: So do I understand correctly that this decreases the scope of the method displayMediaThumb() to only the images[0] property?

Comment: Or maybe not decrease, but just determines the scope?

Comment: @Lexib0y I'm not understanding the question. The scope of `displayMediaThumb` must be public since it's being called from outside the class that defines it. Maybe you mean which instance of an image object it's being called on?  That would be the first since `[0]` is getting the top object out of the array.

Comment: Although I was aware of the possibility that an array can hold object, I did not connect the dots... Lack of experience I guess. Thanks for the help!